# Taking n steps forward and m steps back: probability of returning where you started if n and m are determined by random dice rolls.

Tags: probability

You've all heard the phrase "Three steps forward, two steps back."

I am trying to figure out the probability of returning to my starting point if the number of steps forward is determined by rolling one six-sided die and the number of steps backward is determined by rolling another six-sided die.

Let's call rolling both dice a "trip." So if I roll a 3 on die #1, I go forward 3 steps, and then I roll a 2 on die #2, I go backward 2 steps.  My total distance covered in the 'trip' is 1 step.

What is the probability that I return to the origin after 1 trip?  What is the probability after 2 trips?  What is the probability after n trips?

Comment: If you use a blue die for the forward steps, and a red die for the backward steps, you want to know the probability that the sum of the blue die is equal to the sum of the red die after $n$ throws of each. So for one step it's $1/6$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difficulty in this problem lies in the calculation of the number of different ways a sum of n throws of a die can be determined. For one throw the probability that the 'sum' of the second die equals the first is $\frac{1}{6}$, which is calculated by adding the probabilities of rolling the same number on two dice i.e. $6\times \frac{1}{6^2} = \frac{1}{6}$

For two throws you need to add together the probabilities of rolling each possible two dice total (i.e. 2, 3, 4 ... 12). The probability of a single throw is $$P_{total}=\frac{\text{Number of ways to roll the total}}{\text{Total number of possible rolls}}$$We square because we need the probability of it happening on the first die ***and*** the second (and = multiply). This is relatively simple:

$$\begin{matrix}
\text{Total for 2 dice}:&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12\\
\text{Number of ways to roll}:&1&2&3&4&5&6&5&4&3&2&1\\
\text{Probability}:&\bigr(\frac{1}{36}\big)^2&\bigr(\frac{2}{36}\big)^2&\bigr(\frac{3}{36}\big)^2&\bigr(\frac{4}{36}\big)^2&\bigr(\frac{5}{36}\big)^2&\bigr(\frac{6}{36}\big)^2&\bigr(\frac{5}{36}\big)^2&\bigr(\frac{4}{36}\big)^2&\bigr(\frac{3}{36}\big)^2&\bigr(\frac{2}{36}\big)^2&\bigr(\frac{1}{36}\big)^2
\end{matrix}$$

Summing all the probabilities, which are all the different ways that the sum of the two rolls on the first dice  equal the sum on the second, we get $$\frac{1}{36^2}(1^2+2^2+3^2+4^2+5^2+6^2+5^2+4^2+3^2+2^2+1^2) = \frac{73}{648}$$

Which is less than what we get for one trip, which makes sense when you think that there are many more ways to *not* be at the origin.

For three trips (this will be the last individual case I will work through) I wrote down the permutations of 3 dice rolling to achieve every outcome $k$ such that $3\le k\le6\times3$ which are all the possible totals for three dice.

I realised after a while that there was a pattern, and then after trying the first few for 4 trips I concluded that there was a Pascals triangular number thing going on. It arises because when writing down all the permutations you find that one number is fixed while the others permute through something you have done before i.e. for $n=2$. Then you move up the fixed number and repeat the process until the list is exhausted. This is hard to explain in words but makes sense if you write down the permutations orderly by hand.

**For $n$ trips**, the number of different ways of rolling a specific total $k$ where the allowed $k$ are given by $n\le k \le 6n$ are given by the $(k-n+1)^{th}$ column in the $n^{th}$ row of this modified Pascals triangle:

$$\begin{matrix}
    &&&&&&&&&&1&&1&&1&&1&&1&&1\\
    &&&&&1&&2&&3&&4&&5&&6&&5&&4&&3&&2&&1\\
1&&3&&6&&10&&15&&21&&25&&27&&27&&25&&21&&15&&10&&6&&3&&1
    \end{matrix}$$

where each number is the sum of the **6** numbers above it i.e. 3 on either side. Only the first three rows are given because otherwise it would be much too wide.

So for 3 trips we have $$\left( \frac{1}{6^3}\ \right)^2(1^2+3^2+6^2+...+27^2+27^2+25^2+...+3^2+1^2)=\frac{361}{3888}$$

To generalise to $n$ trips using this method you would need to expand the modified 'Dicey' triangle out to row n, sum the square of every element in the row, and divide by $6^{2n}$.

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed explanation!  The modified Pascal's triangle is fascinating. I though of another wrinkle: can you suggest a way for me to find out the probability if I want to calculate how likely it is tihat I never pass the origin? In the current problem, I could take two steps forward and three steps back. But what if I pretend the origin is a wall and that I can't take any steps backward through it. Would this involve a conditional probability? It seems to me that I would have to know that none of the previous dice rolls made me take more steps backward than I took forward.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not the approach you're after but anyway, here we go.

By writing a small C-program that accumulates whether or not we arrived at position zero after n steps and running it over very many trials, we get the probability as a function of n. Here is the code:

```
    #include <string.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <strings.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <assert.h>

    #define randf() ((double) rand () / ((double) RAND_MAX+1))
    #define rand6() ((int) (randf () * 6 + 1.0))

    int main (void)
    {
        sranddev ();
        const int trials = 100000000;
        const int N = 200;
        int match[N];
        int fail[N];
        bzero (match, sizeof (match));
        bzero (fail,  sizeof (fail));

        for (int i=0; i<trials; i++)
        {
            int pos = 0;
            for (int n=0; n<N; n++)
            {
                pos += rand6 ();
                pos -= rand6 ();
                if (pos == 0)
                    match[n]++;
                else
                    fail[n]++;
            }
        }

        for (int n=0; n<N; n++)
            printf ("%0.18lf\n", (double) match[n] / (match[n] + fail[n]));
    }
```

By running the program and inserting the data into R we get the following plot:
[image]

With some bruteforce, one finds that by plotting $1 / prob(n)^2$ instead of prob(n), we get a linear function:

[image]

This suggests that the probability can be expressed as p(n)=$1/sqrt(kn+m)$ and by using initial conditions p(0)=1 and p(1)=1/6 we get k=35 and m=1.
To see how this probability fits the experimental data, we get the red line:
[image]

As one can see, it doesn't fit exactly but anyhow, it's a good start :)

Comment: Actually I like this approach!  It gives a much simpler approximate equation to work with than an exact calculation.

Comment: My intuition tells me that the more I roll the dice, the more likely I am to eventually end up at the origin.  This graph tells me my intuition is wrong: my chances of seeing the origin keep getting smaller for bigger and bigger n.  Is this graph implying that, if I rolled the dice an infinite number of times, the chances of me being at the origin at n= infinity are effectively zero?

Comment: Also, does it mean anything mathematically if I do the following:  what if I sum every probability from n=1 to n=infinity?  I think that's called a series, and according to google the series 1/sqrt(n) diverges when all terms are summed.  I don't think it makes sense to say that there is an infinite probability that at some point other than n=0 I was exactly on the origin.  I thought probabilities have to be between 0 and 1.

Comment: The sum of probabilities only $=1$ if a probability distribution function (PDF) is normalised. The $n^{th}$ PDF will describe how the outcome of $n$ trips will be distributed. The probabilities given here are not for the outcomes of the $n^{th}$ trip, but for the probability of the outcome being zero after n trips. The difference is subtle, but means that that the graph given above (which I love!) is not a PDF so summing the probabilities has no meaning. The graph actually decays ***inversely*** to the number of growing final position possibilities.